# useEffect hook not getting called on prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 dropdowns, I need to update the values of the second dropdown based on the first. On page load, I need to initialize the dropdown values based on conditions, like so:

```
    const getInitialState= () => {
            //defaultSelected has a value if saved in DB, if not then I set the 0 option value in type, based on this value option value will be populated in the dropdown. I get all the values from parent component
            let updatedType= defaultSelected !== ""
        ? defaultType
        : Region.RegionType;
        console.log('typeeeee', type)
        return updatedType;
            }
        
              useEffect(() =>{
    //Here in options dropdown values object is set based on type selected 
               let updatedOptions = !_.isEmpty (type)
              ? "a" //value from db if save
              : "b"; //If not 0th value of the object
        
              setOptions(prevOptions => ({
                ...prevOptions,
                ["options"]: updatedOptions 
              }));
          },[type]);
        
          const [type, setType] = useState(getInitialState);
          const [options, setOptions] = useState('');

          const changeCrTypeHandler = (event) =>{
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setType(type =>({
          ...type,
          [name]: value}));
      }

return (
    <>
          <select
            onChange={changeCrTypeHandler}
            style={{ width: "150px" }}
            value={!_.isEmpty(type)}
            name= "type"
          >
            {_.map(customMap, (crId) => { //I get this cusomMap from Parent component
              return (
                <option
                  id={crId.customType}
                  value={crId.customType}
                  key={crId.customType}
                >
                  {crId.customType}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>{" "}
          &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
          <select
            onChange={changeCrHashHandler} //second dropdown onchange
            style={{ width: "250px" }}
            value={crHashId}
            name= "options"
          >
            {_.map(!_.isEmpty(options), (o) => { //This options are created based on type, which is currently not getting set
              return (
                <option
                  id={o.customId}
                  value={o.customId}
                  key={o.customId}
                >
                  {o.name}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
```

Based on type value then I need to set the value of the option.

But my useEffect hook doesn't get called upon changes in type. How can I call the useEffect method whenever there is any changes in the type?

Any help for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The way you have it here `getInitialState` is invoked before `setState` is defined. Just pass the "values based on conditions" to `useState`.

Comment: If you have a complex state object it's generally recommended to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

Comment: I think you simplify your code too much/wrong. This line `},[type]);` should throw you an error that `type` is not declared. And I assume/hope, that in `getInitialState` the `return type;` references some local variable with that name, and not this one `const [type, setType] = useState(getInitialState);`.

Comment: And are you sure that `options` is a state and not just a value derived from `type`? #useMemo. Plus `options` seems to be of type string (all values I see are strings). So what do you expect `({ ...oneString, ...anotherString })` to do?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my code, if it could provide more clarity of that I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setState` before it is defined. For the initial value, you just return it without calling `setState`. For having the second dropdown state depending on the first one's state, you could use the `useEffect` hook, like so:

```js
const [firstDropdown, setFirstDropdown] = useState(getInitialState({type:"", options:""}));
const [secondDropdown, setScondDropdown] = useState(0); // you could use whatever initial value you want here
const getInitialState= () => {
  //some logic to get the value in type
  //just return that inital value without calling setState
  
}
// the function inside useEffect runs every time firstDropdown changes
useEffect(()=>{
  // some logic on firstDropdown
  let value = firstDropdown+25
  setScondDropdown(value)
},[firstDropdown]);
```

**Update**:

In your `useEffect`, change this :

```
 setOptions(prevOptions => ({
                ...prevOptions,
                ["options"]: updatedOptions 
              }));
```

to this :

```
 setOptions(updatedOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the useState as below:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({})
setState((prev) => {
    // do whatever you want to do with the previous state
})
```

And for the name, please do not use setState as your setter function of useState. because setState is another method in the class based components in React